Avalonia: how to get the data of a control where the sender belongs to?
My program requires a drag-and-drop. when i move a 'part' rectangle into another 'raw material' rectangle, it's successfully added to where i dropped but i need to remove the moved part from its original location. but i am struggling to get the data of the raw material where the dragged part belonged to... i guess it's because part rectangle is not directly parented with the raw material rectangle but i have no idea how to solve this 
AXAML
<!-- Parts arranged inside raw materials -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DragDrop.AllowDrop="True">
                    <ItemsControl Name="RawMaterialList" ItemsSource="{Binding DragAndDropData.ArrangedRawMaterials}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Canvas Width="1200" Height="40">
                                    <!-- Raw material -->
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Rectangle Name="RawMaterialRectangle" Height="30" Width="{Binding Length, Converter={StaticResource DivideByTenConverter}}" Fill="LightGray" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="5"
                                                   DragDrop.AllowDrop="True" Tag="{Binding}" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <!-- Parts -->
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PartsInside}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle Name="PartRectangle" Height="30" Width="{Binding Length, Converter={StaticResource DivideByTenConverter}}" Fill="BurlyWood"
                                                               PointerPressed="Part_PointerPressed" DragDrop.AllowDrop="True" Tag="{Binding }"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </Canvas>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>


The data structure of Bound ItemsSource:

A list of RawMaterial ('ArrangedRawMaterials' in the code)
RawMaterial contains a list of Parts ('PartsInside' in the code)



Drag-And-Drop Event Handler
private void Part_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerPressedEventArgs e)
{
        var part = (sender as Control)?.DataContext as Part;
        
        var partRectangle = sender as Rectangle;
        var rawMaterialRectangle = partRectangle?.GetVisualParent<Rectangle>();

        var rawMaterial = rawMaterialRectangle?.Tag as RawMaterial;


rawMaterial is always null...
and if i remove the rectangle type from the GetVisualParent, it selects the border tag that wraps the part rectangle tag

How it looks like

